# ProcessMessages() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to drop a div down to a certain height to display some additional content. For that I wrote following dropbox() function:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function sleep(milliseconds) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
          if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
          break;
          }
        }
      }

  function dropbox(element){
    var obj = document.getElementById(element);
    if(obj) {
      var element = document.getElementById(element),
          style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
          height = style.getPropertyValue('height');
          height = height.substring(0,2);
      var i = 0;
      for (i = height; i<200; i++)
        {
        sleep(100);
        var tst = i+"px";
        //alert(tst);
        obj.style.height = tst;
        }
        //alert(i);

    } else {
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Now the problem I'm experiencing is, the box actually isn't visible during the roll down process but only after the loop has completed but I want it to look like the "Check Availability"-box on http://www.thedana.com/. How do I get this accomplished?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you dump example code to jsfiddle.net and/or provide your HTML as well?  It's hard to help you debug anything with so much information missing.  Also, have you considered jQuery?  It certainly isn't necessary to do this type of thing, but does make it much easier.

Comment: Brad, certainly can, the implementation is on http://quaaoutlodge.com/drupal-7.14 (by the Book Now button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code. It may help you

```
<div class="right_content">

         We deliver quick and easy registration.
        Mysites.com is our hosting server and we've buit our website under observation of Mysite.com

      </div>
        <p class="flip">Know About us</p>
     </div>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").mouseover(function(){
        $(".right_content").slideToggle("slow");
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: This is jQuery.  Where did the OP ask for jQuery or illustrate that they wanted to use jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use looping delays in browser javascript as it will make the browser unresponsive to both input and screen updating and waste the battery on a mobile device.

Instead, you should use `setTimeout()` which lets you schedule an activity for some time in the future.  Good animation uses a tweening algorithm that schedules the next tick of the animation, then compares the elapsed time and calculates where the next animation step should be drawn and is continually self correcting in this way.

Also, if you do a Google search for `javascript animation`, you will find many helpful pieces of prewritten code for doing animation with plain javascript.  In addition, all the major javascript libraries (such as jQuery or YUI) have significant animation capabilities built in and already written for you.

Here's a simple example:

```
function dropbox(elem, finalHt, duration) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var tick = 20;
    var startHt = parseInt(elem.style.height, 10);
    var growHt = finalHt - startHt;

    function next() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var percent = (now - start) / duration;
        var target = Math.round(startHt + (growHt * percent));
        elem.style.height = Math.min(target, finalHt) + "px";
        if (target < finalHt) {
            setTimeout(next, tick);
        }
    }

    setTimeout(next, tick);
}


function run() {
    var item = document.getElementById("box"); 
    item.style.height = "10px";    
    dropbox(item, 300, 2000);
}
```

Working example and more generalized code: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/QxXMK/